# Teradata - duplication column error

Tags: teradata

I want to make a volatile table using teradata.
In the select statement I am using multiple columns from different tables.
However, some of the columns in the different tables have same names.
Therefore, I am getting a 'duplication column error'.

The question is - is there any workaround to bypass this error?
Is it possible to add for example table name to column name?

This is how my code looks:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE test
AS (
SEL *
FROM Table_A Left JOIN Table_B
...
)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

Comment: Select individual columns instead of select *, and alias them.  As in `select Table_A.col1 as SomeCleverName,...`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a select * , select individual column names and put aliases next to it. This will bypass the error.

Answer (score -1):

A *select all* statement only works if you're working off one table. If you're retrieving all data from multiple tables, you've to specify that in your select statement.

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE test AS
    (
    SELECT      Table_A.*
                , Table_B.*
    FROM        Table_A
    LEFT JOIN   Table_B ON ...
    ...
    )
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(«PI»)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```